# python - Ftp upload file in directory structure per /year/month/day

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using the following function to upload files and structure per week day ,

what i'm looking to adjust here to change the directory structure to be per year/month/day

example /Incoming/2016/02/08/filename

if the dir or sub dir is not exits it will create it then upload

which method should be use to switch from per week day to deep dir structure per year/month/day

```
def dir_today ():
    """ Function to determine directory today """
    week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    day = week[datetime.today().weekday()]
    return day

def ftp_upload (ifn):
        """" FTP upload Function. Destination file will be appended with date and timecode received from meta data"""
        src = "%s/%s" % (src_loc,ifn)
        try:
                create_time = get_meta(ifn)
        except:
                create_time = datetime.now().strftime("VID_%Y-%m-%d_T_%H-%M-%S")
        dst_file = os.path.splitext(ifn)[0] + os.path.splitext(ifn)[1]
        upload_directory = ftp_base_directory + '/' + dir_today() + '/'

        try:
                ftp_connect = ftplib.FTP(ftp_server, ftp_login, ftp_password)

                try:
                        ftp_connect.cwd(upload_directory)
                except ftplib.all_errors:
                        ftp_connect.mkd(upload_directory)
                        ftp_connect.cwd(upload_directory)

                file = open(src, "rb")
                send = ftp_connect.storbinary("STOR "+ dst_file, file)
                ftp_connect.close
                file.close()
                os.remove(src)

                logger.info("Moved file %s" %(src))

                oflist.remove(ifn)
                hsize.pop(ifn)
                uploaded.insert(0,ifn)
                try:
                        uploaded.pop(9)
                except:
                        pass
        except Exception as e:
                logger.info("Error: %s" %(repr(e)))

        return
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just modify `dir_today()` to return the subpath:

```
def dir_today():
    today = date.today()
    return '{day.year}/{day.month}/{day.day}'.format(day=today)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively:

```
>>> def dir_today():
...  return datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
... 
>>> dir_today()
'2016/02/08'
```